# Firebird connection to remote server using FbConnectionStringBuilder

Tags: client-server, database-connection, firebird, interbase

We're having trouble connecting to a remote Firebird server using the .NET provider FbConnectionStringBuilder class. We can connect to a local database file in either embedded or server mode however when it comes to establishing a connection to a remote server we can't establish the connection.

We assign properties of the FbConnectionStringBuilder class with the following code (server mode). I have omitted the code which assigns properties for embedded mode.

```
var cs = new FbConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Database = databaseSessionInfo.PathAbsoluteToDatabase,
    Charset = "UTF8",
    Dialect = 3,
};

cs.DataSource = databaseSessionInfo.Hostname;
cs.Port = databaseSessionInfo.Port;
cs.ServerType = (FbServerType)databaseSessionInfo.Mode;
cs.Pooling = true;
cs.ConnectionLifeTime = 30;

if (databaseSessionInfo.UseCustomUserAccount)
{
    cs.UserID = databaseSessionInfo.Username;
    cs.Password = databaseSessionInfo.Password;
}
else
{
    cs.UserID = Constants.DB_DefaultUsername;
    cs.Password = Constants.DB_DefaultPassword;
}
```

Pretty straightforward. Our software contains a connection configuration screen whereby a user can supply different connection properties. These properties get assigned to the FbConnectionStringBuilder class using the code above.

The connection builder class outputs a connection string in the following format:

*initial catalog="P:\Source\database.fdb";character set=UTF8;dialect=3;data source=localhost;port number=3050;server type=Default;pooling=True;connection lifetime=30;user id=USER;password=example*

However literature on Firebird connection strings as indicated on this page ([Firebird Connection Strings](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq260/)) talk of a different structure. I can only assume the FbConnectionStringBuilder class builds a Firebird connection string satisfying the requirements of Firebird.

1. Does the FbConnectionStringBuilder class append the hostname to the connection string correctly?
2. The Firebird server is running on the server. I assume there is no need to install it on the client?
3. What libraries need to be installed with the client to support a remote server connection?
4. Are we doing this right?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions:

1) Yes it will.

2) Correct, the client library will connect over the network.

3) If you use the ADO library, just FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll

4) Maybe, I dont know if this will help but this is how I connect.

```
FbConnectionStringBuilder ret = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
ret.DataSource = Host;
ret.Port = Port;
ret.Database = Database;
ret.UserID = User;
ret.Password = Password;
ret.Charset = CharacterSet; 
FbConnection ret = new FbConnection(connectionString);
```

Interestingly, what is the absolute path you are providing to the StringBuilder ?  Is it the server absolute path, or some kind of network mapped drive?

Also, I assume you've reviewed firewall settings and allowing port 3050 inbound.

Comment: 'absolute path', this is the path to the database file. The most common configuration for our software is to connect to a local database file, this path points to that file. If the database is located on a server what should the "database" field contain? Should it just contain the database filename and nothing else because 'host' will provide the address to the file?

Comment: In case of using server it is best to use database alias - see the aliases.conf file in your Firebird server root.

Comment: As ain mentioned it is best to specify the alias for the database in aliases.conf.   Otherwise, if on Server X the database is on C:\data\base.fdb , then you must supply "C:\data\base.fdb"  as the Database path.